# How to extract semantic facts from Wikipedia

Tags: web-crawler

I want to write a program that goes through wikipedia pages and extracts semantic facts in the form ("subject", "relation", "object"). Example of the fact may be ("Age Of Empire", "developed by" ,"Ensemble Studios"). How can something like this be done?

Comment: That's a very deep quagmire you're getting into :D. [Take a look at this, for example.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjFxK2jj-PoAhWjSt8KHZdqADUQFjACegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.acm.org%2Fft_gateway.cfm%3Fid%3D3324473%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw376hoa9Wcts_hgE-tQimyO)

Comment: Instead of offering a bounty and asking for a complete solution, you should probably share your effort so far, so that others can help you.

Comment: But this is a board topic, I'm just gathering ideas...

Comment: If you want facts from Wikipedia you can reduce the time scrapping by ignoring all social/political "articles" and ignore other aspects like how "nah, X element doesn't cause cancer, go eat five pounds of it every day!" In short: be very wary of what you consider "facts".

Comment: You don't need to cruwl, wikipedia has a downlodable archive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Answer (score 5):

This is an **actively researched problem.** A good start to get up to speed, is the [Broccoli Engine of the University Freiburg](http://broccoli.cs.uni-freiburg.de/demos/BroccoliFreebase/). They had to solve exactly this problem and additionally had to make the resulting dataset usable. There are quite a few interesting [publications](http://broccoli.cs.uni-freiburg.de/publications/) and especially the Paper on **[Open Information Extraction via Contextual Sentence Decomposition (PDF)](http://ad-publications.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/ICSC_csdie_BH_2013.pdf)** will be of interest to your problem. You may also be interested in their [subsequent research](http://ad.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/projekte).

If you **just need the data** for something, there are easier ways to get it - at least a good part. There was a big fact database openly available called [Freebase](https://developers.google.com/freebase/) that was acquired by Google and subsequently deactivated in favour of [WikiData](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page). Unfortunately they had [problems](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/freebase-discuss/WEnyO8f7xOQ) unifying the datasets. Luckily the **[whole freebase dataset](https://developers.google.com/freebase/)** is still available for download.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of scraping Wikipedia, you may be better off looking at [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page) (they're both run by the Wikimedia Foundation). Wikidata acts as central storage for the structured data of its Wikimedia sister projects including Wikipedia.

Here's the wikidata link for Age of Empires II: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q34852

Alternatively, you may scrape the underlying [infobox templates field metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_date_field_metadata) (or extract it directly from the raw wikitext templates).

Both Wikipedia and Wikidata are available via APIs or in offline versions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are your motivations but I suggest that you start with [downloading Wikipedia's database](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/) which is already well structured and offers relations ([torrent version](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dump_torrents)).

Have a look at the database schema [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Manual:Database_layout/diagram&action=render) may help you to get a grasp on how things are architected.

You can access to chosen bits of the database through [Kiwix packages](https://wiki.kiwix.org/wiki/Content_in_all_languages)  and then do some processing over it with [ZIM tools](https://wiki.openzim.org/wiki/Bindings).

Of course don't forget that Wikipedia is powered by Mediawiki which is open source thus its [code is freely available](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki).

As you can imagine you're not the first one to have interest in data mining Wikipedia and I recommend that you read [this paper](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ihw/papers/12-DM-IHW-OStoolkit-wikimining.pdf) where a team of researchers explain how they put together a [Wikipedia Miner Toolkit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wikipedia-miner/) based on some AI (NLP). It's a bit old but still of interest.

Depending on your plans, for simpler usage you can use [Wikipedia's API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page).

Answer (score 0):

Here are few ideas:

- You can utilize Machine Learning, and more specifically NLP or (Natural Language Processing) to parse web pages, and based on the parsed content to be able to generate facts, or complete sentences, or even answer questions, like (by your example) "Who is the developer of Age Of Empire?"
- Another way you can do this, it of course with a web-crawler, but then, once you have gathered ANY information (which would be the easy part), you somehow need to reduce that data, classify it and create a logic that would make sense of it, which again leads me (personally) to Machine learning generalization..